# How to remove a particular item using jquery in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am creating images using ajax.

I am appending newly added images like this

**create.js.erb**

```
$("#photos .row").append("<%= j render(@photo) %>")
```

**_photo.html.erb**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading-preview">
      <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%= link_to listing_photo_path(@listing, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
                <% end %>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my view file where everything happens:  **index.html.erb**

```
<div id="photos">
    <div class="row">
    <%= render @photos %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Everything above works fine..but how to remove an image using ajax???

**listings_controller.rb**

```
def destroy
    @photo = @listing.photos.find(params[:id])
    @photo_id=@photo.id
    @photo.destroy
 end
```

**destroy.js.erb**

> So in destroy how can I remove an image? via ajax??The destroy method is currently working but need to refresh the page to see the effect. How can I grab the deleted photo and remove that from view??

**update**

```
<div id="photos">
    <div class="row">

# This will be one image
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading-preview">
      <img src="https://testing-dev-1.amazonaws.com/cache/c75fda133cc1706a83409a2d9f948adfaf4f98533f64f2a17fbb27b06a2a?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIL6J323MJQNSQPOQ%2F20151217%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20151217T161738Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=984baa326e5673e9c98c9edd94ce0e18ea58f2dd71da59e9061e5039caefbe73" alt="C75fda133cc1706a83409a2d9f948adfaf4f98533f64f2a17fbb27b06a2a?x amz algorithm=aws4 hmac sha256&amp;x amz credential=akiail6j323mjqnsqpoq%2f20151217%2fap southeast 1%2fs3%2faws4 request&amp;x amz date=20151217t161738z&amp;x amz expires=900&amp;x amz signedheaders=host&amp;x amz signature=984baa326e5673e9c98c9edd94ce0e18ea58f2dd71da59e9061e5039caefbe73">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/listings/1/photos/35">
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
</a>          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
# The first image end

# This will be second image
    <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading-preview">
      <img src="https://testing-dev-1.amazonaws.com/cache/c75fda133cc1706a83409a2d9f948adfaf4f98533f64f2a17fbb27b06a2a?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIL6J323MJQNSQPOQ%2F20151217%2Fap-southeast-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz-Date=20151217T161738Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=900&amp;X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz-Signature=984baa326e5673e9c98c9edd94ce0e18ea58f2dd71da59e9061e5039caefbe73" alt="C75fda133cc1706a83409a2d9f948adfaf4f98533f64f2a17fbb27b06a2a?x amz algorithm=aws4 hmac sha256&amp;x amz credential=akiail6j323mjqnsqpoq%2f20151217%2fap southeast 1%2fs3%2faws4 request&amp;x amz date=20151217t161738z&amp;x amz expires=900&amp;x amz signedheaders=host&amp;x amz signature=984baa326e5673e9c98c9edd94ce0e18ea58f2dd71da59e9061e5039caefbe73">
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/listings/1/photos/35">
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
</a>          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
# The second image end



</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: pass in the html `id` attribute of the deleted image to your `destroy.js` file through the controller, and remove the element with that `id` from the page!

Comment: @SunnyK How  can I target the div with id on the updated code using jquery?? This is from a single image example. Each photo will be in a div with class ="col-md-4"...I am finding it extremely difficult to get into the part where the id is..

Comment: How to target div with an id??? `Document.getElementById` !!!! Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @SunnyK No sorry its my bad.. I was thinking something and writing something else..now am unable to edit as 5 minutes passed..I meant  the id of the photo..sorry that it misleaded..was a long day and I think now its time to call it a day..

Comment: How are you rendering the photos on the page? You can use [Dom id](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/RecordIdentifier/dom_id) to give each a uniq id.

Comment: @SunnyK I am confused because the photo id is in a link.. I updated the question as its been rendered

Comment: What you need to update is your `_photo.html.erb` partial. I will put this in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `_photo.html.erb` partial to hold unique `id`s as follow:

```
<div class="col-md-4" id="<%= dom_id(photo) %>">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading-preview">
      <%= image_tag photo.image_url(:thumb) %>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
          <span class="pull-right">
            <%= link_to listing_photo_path(@listing, photo), remote: true, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
      <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i>
                <% end %>
          </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This addition of `id="<%= dom_id(photo) %>"` will give each photo a unique `id`, and then, you can target this `id` from your `destroy.js.erb` file, to remove the div with said `id` from the page.

Comment: great thanks.. I havent checked it, but it looks like this is the thing am looking for. I didnt know before about that dom_id thing before..This is a life saver..Again 2 times in a single day..Thanks a lot..

Comment: 2 times? anyways, check and let me know how it worked out.

Comment: ya you had answered my another question on "passing id of a nested resource for deleting a file in rails"..Yes I will let you know..